# Powershell Script to count a text present in a URL

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell trying to learn the basics. I have been provided with some sample code which I am unable to understand. If anyone can provide detailed step by step explanation of the code, it will be of great help to me.

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("url")]
    $siteurl,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("list")]
    $listname,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("workflow")]
    $workflowname
    )

$site = Get-SPSite $siteurl
$web = $site.RootWeb;
$list = $web.Lists[$listname];
$statusChoices = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName($workflowname,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture).BaseTemplate.GetStatusChoices($web);

$countChoices = $statusChoices.count;

Write-Host 'Status Choice count - ' $countChoices;

$i = 0;

while($i -lt $countChoices)
{
  Write-Host $i ' - ' $statusChoices[$i];
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by Step

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("url")]
    $siteurl,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("list")]
    $listname,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [alias("workflow")]
    $workflowname
    )
```

You have to pass above parameters (`$siteurl`, `$listname` and `$workflowname`)  when you will run this `.ps1` file via command line.

```
$site = Get-SPSite $siteurl
```

Connecting with the site via `$siteurl` parameter

```
$web = $site.RootWeb;
```

Getting the `$web`

```
$list = $web.Lists[$listname];
```

Getting list via `$listname` parameter

```
$statusChoices = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName($workflowname,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture).BaseTemplate.GetStatusChoices($web);
```

Getting all [GetStatusChoices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543166.aspx)

```
$countChoices = $statusChoices.count;

Write-Host 'Status Choice count - ' $countChoices;
```

Getting and printing total number of `$statusChoices`

```
$i = 0;

while($i -lt $countChoices)
{
  Write-Host $i ' - ' $statusChoices[$i];
  $i++;
}
```

Looping and printing `$statusChoices`

**PS:** I am not good at coding. I search, understand and then copypaste.

Comment: When trying to run this script I'm getting this error. I tried hard, but can't find any solution.

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At E:\PowerShellScript\AppSupport\Development\test.ps1:12 char:65+ $statusChoices = $list.WorkflowAssociations.GetAssociationByName <<<< ($workflowname,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture).BaseTemplate.GetSta
tusChoices($web)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetAssociationByName:String)
   [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: In your question you have asked about the steps not about the error. You can ask another about error. I will try to help